# Forward slash between variables

Tags: php

I just came across some example code which used a forward slash between variables...
I'm not sure if this is a typo or an actual function. And because I get a lot of regex-hits when I search on Google, I thought I might ask it here.

It's about this line:

```
$context['finished'] = $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
```

So, the meaning of the forward slash between those two variables is...?

Comment: Division operator?

Comment: It's a division. It's like `2 / 2 = 1` or `30 / 3 = 10`

Comment: its arithmetic division operator..!
that's what happens by thinking too much..

Comment: how much programming do you know ?

Comment: How much grade school arithmetic do you knkow?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic [arithmetic operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Comment: +1 for thinking too much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [division operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: Are you still doubting `I think` ?

Comment: flood it with `&nbsp;` !

Comment: Michiel - u have many many badges....this must be a trick question right ?  :)

Comment: You learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @MarcoZen, no it's a stupid question... I didn't thought of something so simple. As redDevil said, I was simply thinking too much. Stupid question! I wish I hadn't asked it because it made me look very stupid

Comment: Come on, don't take it so hard, nobody's perfect. Enjoy your day ;)

Comment: Just move on buddy .... and keep making things happen !!!